# Predicting recidivism for male prisoners

Tags: predictive-models, survival, conditional-probability, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

The following question takes ground in the [this example](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf) with time varying covariates. The following code will read data from a url, parse it to the right format (allowing for time varying covariates) and fit a Cox Proportional Hazards model:

```
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(tcltk)

Unfold <- function(){
  # require(survival)
  if (!activeDataSetP()) return()
  initializeDialog(title=gettext("Reshape Wide Survival Data to Long", 
                                 domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
  .activeDataSet <- ActiveDataSet()
  dsname <- tclVar(paste(.activeDataSet, ".long", sep=""))
  dsnameFrame <- tkframe(top)
  entryDsname <- ttkentry(dsnameFrame, width="20", textvariable=dsname)
  nCovSets <- 0
  .CovSets <- list()
  .CovNames <- character(0)
  onOK <- function(){
    if (nCovSets == 0){
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                     message=gettext("No time-varying covariates specified.", 
                                     domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
      return()
    }
    dsnameValue <- trim.blanks(tclvalue(dsname))
    if (dsnameValue == "") {
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                     message=gettext("You must enter the name of a data set.", 
                                     domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
      return()
    }
    if (!is.valid.name(dsnameValue)) {
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                     message=paste('"', dsnameValue, '" ', gettext("is not a valid name.", 
                                                                   domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), sep=""))
      return()
    }
    if (is.element(dsnameValue, listDataSets())) {
      if ("no" == tclvalue(checkReplace(dsnameValue, gettext("Data set", 
                                                             domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival")))){
        tkdestroy(top)
        Unfold()
        return()
      }
    }
    time <- getSelection(timeBox)
    if (length(time) == 0){
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold, 
                     message=gettext("You must select a time-to-event variable.", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
      return()
    }
    event <- getSelection(eventBox)
    if (length(event) == 0){
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold, message=gettext("You must select an event indicator.", 
                                                    domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
      return()
    }
    lag <- tclvalue(lagSliderValue)
    lag <- if (lag == "0") "" else paste(", lag=", lag, sep="")
    closeDialog()
    con <- textConnection("cov", open="w", local=TRUE)
    dump(".CovSets", file=con)
    close(con)
    cov <- paste(cov, collapse="")
    doItAndPrint(cov)
    command <- paste(dsnameValue, " <- unfold(", .activeDataSet,', time="', time, '", event="', event,
                     '", cov=.CovSets, cov.names=c(', 
                     paste(paste('"', names(.CovSets), '"', sep=""), collapse=","), ')', lag,  ')' , sep="")
    doItAndPrint(command)
    logger("remove(.CovSets)")
    remove(.CovSets, envir=.GlobalEnv)
    tkfocus(CommanderWindow())
    activeDataSet(dsnameValue)
  }
  onCovSelect <- function(){
    covs <- sortVarNames(getSelection(covariateBox))
    if (nCovSets > 0){
      nTimes <- length(.CovSets[[1]])
      if (length(covs) != nTimes) errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                                                 message=sprintf(gettext("Covariate set has %d entries; should have %d entries", 
                                                                         domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), length(covs), nTimes))
      nCovSets <<- nCovSets + 1
    } else {
      if (length(covs) < 2) errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                                           message=gettext("Covariate set must have at least 2 entries.", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"))
      else nCovSets <<- 1
    }
    name <- trim.blanks(tclvalue(covVariableName))
    if (!is.valid.name(name)){
      errorCondition(recall=Unfold,
                     message=paste('"', newVar, '" ',
                                   gettext("is not a valid name.", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), sep=""))
      return()
    }
    if (is.element(name, Variables())) {
      if ("no" == tclvalue(checkReplace(name))){
        tkdestroy(top)
        Unfold()
        return()
      }
    }
    tkconfigure(lagSlider, to=round(length(covs)/4))
    covs <- list(covs)
    names(covs) <- name
    .CovSets <<- c(.CovSets, covs)
    .CovNames <<- c(.CovNames, name)
    tkdelete(newCovBox$listbox, "0", "end")
  for (cov in .CovNames) tkinsert(newCovBox$listbox, "end", cov)
    newCovBox$varlist <<- .CovNames
  tkselection.clear(covariateBox$listbox, "0", "end")
    tclvalue(covVariableName) <- paste("covariate.", nCovSets + 1, sep="")
  }
  OKCancelHelp(helpSubject="Unfold", model=TRUE)
  survFrame <- tkframe(top)
  .activeDataSet <- ActiveDataSet()
  .numeric <- NumericOrDate()
  .factors <- Factors()
  time1 <- eval(parse(text=paste('attr(', .activeDataSet, ', "time1")', sep="")))
  time1 <- if (!is.null(time1)) which(time1 == .numeric) - 1 
  event <- eval(parse(text=paste('attr(', .activeDataSet, ', "event")', sep="")))
  event <- if (!is.null(event)) which(event == Numeric()) - 1 
  timeBox <- variableListBox(survFrame, NumericOrDate(), 
                             title=gettext("Time to event\n(select one)", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"),
                             initialSelection=if(is.null(time1)) NULL else time1)
  eventBox <- variableListBox(survFrame, Numeric(), title=gettext("Event indicator\n(select one)", 
                                                                  domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), initialSelection=event)
  covFrame <- tkframe(top)
  covSelectFrame <- tkframe(covFrame)
  covariateBox <- variableListBox(covSelectFrame, Variables(), 
                                  title=gettext("Select set of\ntime-dependent covariates", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"),
                                  selectmode="multiple")
  covSelectButton <- buttonRcmdr(covSelectFrame, 
                                 text=gettext("Select", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), command=onCovSelect)  
  covVariableName <- tclVar("covariate.1")
  newCovFrame <- tkframe(covFrame)
  newCovariate <- ttkentry(newCovFrame, width="20", textvariable=covVariableName)
  newCovBox <- variableListBox(covFrame, c(gettext("<none defined>", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), rep("", 4)), 
                               title=gettext("Time-dependent covariates", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), initialSelection=-1)
  lagSliderValue <- tclVar("0")
  lagSlider <- tkscale(newCovFrame, from=0, to=10,
                       showvalue=TRUE, variable=lagSliderValue,
                       resolution=1, orient="horizontal")
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(dsnameFrame, text=gettext("Enter name for data set:", 
                                              domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival")), entryDsname, sticky="w")
  tkgrid(dsnameFrame, sticky="w")
  tkgrid(getFrame(timeBox), labelRcmdr(survFrame, text="  "), getFrame(eventBox), sticky="sw")
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(survFrame, text=""))
  tkgrid(survFrame, sticky="w")
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(newCovFrame, text=gettext("Name for covariate", domain="R-RcmdrPlugin.survival"), 
                    fg="blue"), sticky="nw")
  tkgrid(newCovariate, sticky="nw")
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(newCovFrame, text=""))
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(newCovFrame, text="Lag covariates", fg="blue"), sticky="w")
  tkgrid(lagSlider, sticky="nw")
  tkgrid(getFrame(covariateBox), sticky="nw")
  tkgrid(covSelectButton, sticky="ew")
  tkgrid(covSelectFrame, labelRcmdr(covFrame, text="   "), newCovFrame, labelRcmdr(covFrame, text="   "),
         getFrame(newCovBox), sticky="nw")
  tkgrid(covFrame, sticky="w")
  tkgrid(labelRcmdr(top, text=""))
  tkgrid(buttonsFrame, sticky="w")
  dialogSuffix(rows=9, columns=1)
}

unfold <- function(data, ...){
  UseMethod("unfold")
}

unfold.data.frame <- function(data, time, event, cov,
                              cov.names=paste('covariate', '.', 1:ncovs, sep=""),
                              suffix='.time', cov.times=0:ncov, common.times=TRUE, lag=0, 
                              show.progress=TRUE, ...){
  # if (show.progress && !require(tcltk)) stop("tcltk package missing")
  vlag <- function(x, lag) c(rep(NA, lag), x[1:(length(x) - lag)])
  xlag <- function(x, lag) apply(as.matrix(x), 2, vlag, lag=lag)
  all.cov <- unlist(cov)
  if (!is.numeric(all.cov)) all.cov <- which(is.element(names(data), all.cov))
  if (!is.list(cov)) cov <- list(cov)
  ncovs <- length(cov)
  nrow <- nrow(data)
  ncol <- ncol(data)
  ncov <- length(cov[[1]])
  nobs <- nrow*ncov
  if (length(unique(c(sapply(cov, length), length(cov.times) - 1))) > 1)
    stop(paste(
      "all elements of cov must be of the same length and \n",
      "cov.times must have one more entry than each element of cov."))
  var.names <- names(data)
  subjects <- rownames(data)
  omit.cols <- if (!common.times) c(all.cov, cov.times) else all.cov
  keep.cols <- (1:ncol)[-omit.cols]
  factors <- names(data)[keep.cols][sapply(data[keep.cols], is.factor)]
  levels <- lapply(data[factors], levels)
  first.covs <- sapply(cov, function(x) x[1])
  factors.covs <- which(sapply(data[first.covs], is.factor))
  levels.covs <- lapply(data[names(factors.covs)], levels)
  nkeep <- length(keep.cols)
  if (is.numeric(event)) event <- var.names[event]
  events <- sort(unique(data[[event]]))
  if (length(events) > 2 || (!is.numeric(events) && !is.logical(events))) 
    stop("event indicator must have values {0, 1}, {1, 2} or {FALSE, TRUE}")
  if (!(all(events == 0:1) || all(events == c(FALSE, TRUE)))){
    if (all(events = 1:2)) data[[event]] <- data[[event]] - 1
    else stop("event indicator must have values {0, 1}, {1, 2} or {FALSE, TRUE}")
  }
  times <- if (common.times) matrix(cov.times, nrow, ncov + 1, byrow=TRUE)
  else as.matrix(data[, cov.times])
  new.data <- matrix(Inf, nobs, 3 + ncovs + nkeep)
  rownames <- rep("", nobs)
  colnames(new.data) <- c('start', 'stop', paste(event, suffix, sep=""),
                          var.names[-omit.cols], cov.names)
  end.row <- 0
  if (show.progress){
    progress <- myTkProgressBar(title = "Progress", label = "",
                                min = 0, max = 1, initial = 0, width = 300)
    position <- if (is.element("Rcmdr", loadedNamespaces())) 
      paste("+", paste(10 + commanderPosition(), collapse="+"), sep="")
    else "-20+20"
    tkwm.geometry(progress$window, position)
  }
  data <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(data, as.numeric)))
  for (i in 1:nrow){
    if (show.progress){
      info <- sprintf("%d%% percent done", round(100*i/nrow))
      setTkProgressBar(progress, value=i/nrow, label=info)
    }
    start.row <- end.row + 1
    end.row <- end.row + ncov
    start <- times[i, 1:ncov]
    stop <- times[i, 2:(ncov+1)]
    event.time <- ifelse (stop == data[i, time] & data[i, event] == 1, 1, 0)
    keep <- matrix(data[i, -omit.cols], ncov, nkeep, byrow=TRUE)
    select <- apply(matrix(!is.na(data[i, all.cov]), ncol=ncovs), 1, all)
    rows <- start.row:end.row
    cov.mat <- xlag(matrix(data[i, all.cov], nrow=length(rows)), lag)
    new.data[rows[select], ] <-
      cbind(start, stop, event.time, keep, cov.mat)[select,]
    rownames[rows] <- paste(subjects[i], '.', seq(along=rows), sep="")
  }
  row.names(new.data) <- rownames
  new.data <- as.data.frame(new.data[new.data[, 1] != Inf &
                                       apply(as.matrix(!is.na(new.data[, cov.names])), 1, all), ])
  for (fac in factors){
    new.data[[fac]] <- factor(levels[[fac]][new.data[[fac]]])
  }
  fcv <- 0
  for (cv in factors.covs){
    fcv <- fcv + 1
    new.data[[cov.names[cv]]] <- factor(levels.covs[[fcv]][new.data[[cov.names[cv]]]])
  }
  attr(new.data, "time1") <- "start"
  attr(new.data, "time2") <- "stop"
  attr(new.data, "event") <- paste(event, suffix, sep="")
  close(progress)
  new.data
}

# the following is a modified version of tkProgressBar() from tcltk:

myTkProgressBar <-
  function (title = "R progress bar", label = "", min = 0, max = 1, 
            initial = 0, width = 300) 
  {
    useText <- FALSE
    have_ttk <- as.character(tcl("info", "tclversion")) >= "8.5"
    if (!have_ttk && as.character(tclRequire("PBar")) == "FALSE") 
      useText <- TRUE
    .win <- tktoplevel()
    .val <- initial
    .killed <- FALSE
    tkwm.geometry(.win, sprintf("%dx80", width + 40))
    tkwm.title(.win, title)
    #   fn <- tkfont.create(family = "helvetica", size = 12)
    if (useText) {
      #     .lab <- tklabel(.win, text = label, font = fn, padx = 20)
      .lab <- tklabel(.win, text = label, padx = 20)
      tkpack(.lab, side = "left")
      fn2 <- tkfont.create(family = "helvetica", size = 16)
      .vlab <- tklabel(.win, text = "0%", font = fn2, padx = 20)
      tkpack(.vlab, side = "right")
      up <- function(value) {
        if (!is.finite(value) || value < min || value > max) 
          return()
        .val <<- value
        tkconfigure(.vlab, text = sprintf("%d%%", round(100 * 
                                                          (value - min)/(max - min))))
      }
    }
    else {
      #     .lab <- tklabel(.win, text = label, font = fn, pady = 10)
      .lab <- tklabel(.win, text = label, pady = 10)
      .tkval <- tclVar(0)
      tkpack(.lab, side = "top")
      #     tkpack(tklabel(.win, text = "", font = fn), side = "bottom")
      tkpack(tklabel(.win, text = ""), side = "bottom")
      pBar <- if (have_ttk) 
        ttkprogressbar(.win, length = width, variable = .tkval)
      else tkwidget(.win, "ProgressBar", width = width, variable = .tkval)
      tkpack(pBar, side = "bottom")
      up <- function(value) {
        if (!is.finite(value) || value < min || value > max) 
          return()
        .val <<- value
        tclvalue(.tkval) <<- 100 * (value - min)/(max - min)
      }
    }
    getVal <- function() .val
    kill <- function() if (!.killed) {
      tkdestroy(.win)
      .killed <<- TRUE
    }
    title <- function(title) tkwm.title(.win, title)
    lab <- function(label) tkconfigure(.lab, text = label)
    tkbind(.win, "<Destroy>", kill)
    up(initial)
    structure(list(getVal = getVal, up = up, title = title, label = lab, 
                   kill = kill, window=.win), class = "tkProgressBar")
  }

# read data
Rossi = read.table("http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt", header=T)
Rossi.2 = unfold(Rossi, time="week", event="arrest", cov=11:62, cov.names = "employed")
Rossi.2$id = as.integer(substr(row.names(Rossi.2),1,unlist(gregexpr("\\.", row.names(Rossi.2)))-1))
row.names(Rossi.2) = 1:dim(Rossi.2)[1]

# fit the model
mod.allison.2 = coxph(Surv(start, stop, arrest.time) ~ fin + age + race + wexp + mar + paro + prio + employed, data=Rossi.2)
summary(mod.allison.2)
```

The data is right censored about whether prisoners will recidivism after they've been released. Each week it is recorded whether the inmate have gotten a job or not. Now this is all fine how can I answer the following question using my model?

*What is the probability that the following inmate will experience recidivism within the next 6 weeks? Put another way; what are $P(T_i > 6 + 16| F_{16})$?*

```
   start stop arrest.time fin age  race wexp     mar paro prio employed
1      0    1           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1       no
2      1    2           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1       no
3      2    3           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1       no
4      3    4           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1       no
5      4    5           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1       no
6      5    6           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
7      6    7           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
8      7    8           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
9      8    9           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
10     9   10           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
11    10   11           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
12    11   12           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
13    12   13           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
14    13   14           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
15    14   15           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
16    15   16           0 yes  23 black  yes married  yes    1      yes
```

Now I imagine that I might be able to use something like this

```
predict_inmate = data.frame(
  start=0:15,
  stop=1:16,
  arrest.time=0, fin="yes", age=23, race="black", wexp="yes", mar="married", paro="yes", prio=1, 
  employed=c(rep("no", 5), rep("yes", 11))
)
plot(survfit(mod.allison.2, newdata = predict_inmate), lty=1:2, col=3:4)
legend("bottomleft", c("not employed", "employed"), lty=1:2, col=3:4, bty="n")
abline(v=max(predict_inmate$stop), lty=2)
abline(v=max(predict_inmate$stop)+6, lty=3)
```

Which produces the following graph

[image]

I suppose I am looking for the conditional survival distribution but can I do something for the next-best?

Comment: They are using AI prediction to determine sentencing/parole.  The prediction isn't necessarily "wrong", whatever that means, but it must account for its own results.  That is likely not encoded into the data, so it might do well if treated as a hidden variable.

Comment: @EngrStudent When you say 'they', who are you talking about then? To be honest I don't really know what you are talking about?

Comment: I was thinking about [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/downloads/publications/jdthesis17.pdf), and [this](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/4/1/eaao5580.full), when referring to "them".

Answer (score 0):

So I came across [Dynamic Predictions with Time-Dependent Covariates
in Survival Analysis using Joint Modeling and
Landmarking](http://www.drizopoulos.com/pdf/papers/BiomJrn_JMvsLM_paper.pdf) and thought I'd give the simple *Landmarking* approach a try. In short:

1. Select subjects at risk at time $t$ (now / landmark time).
2. Fit a Cox model to these subjects using by resetting time to zero being the landmark time and using their current covariates.

The downside is it only uses current covariates and not the path history. Anyways in the following I *pretend standing at week 26 and are interested in who are most likely to experience recidivism for the following 26 weeks*.

```
# imagine we have a model and are observing inmates who've been released 26 weeks ago
time_today = 26  
look_ahead_time = 26

# determine all active inmates and the number of actual recidivismed prisoners in the timehorizon
active_ids = unique(Rossi.2$id[Rossi.2$stop > time_today])
arrested_ids = Rossi.2$id[(Rossi.2$stop > time_today) & Rossi.2$arrest.time == 1]

# Use landmarking (move time zero to now and fit to current covariates)
recidivism_prob = function(id, inmate_data, time_horizon){

  # keep covariates from last observation. 
  inmate_data = inmate_data[inmate_data$stop == max(inmate_data$stop),]

  # fit model to covariates
  fit_to_covariate = survfit(mod.allison.2, newdata = inmate_data)

  # calc risk of recidivism_prob within a certain time horizon (note this is the time zero part)
  1-fit_to_covariate$surv[fit_to_covariate$time == look_ahead_time]
}

# run through each active prisoner and determine the risk of recidivism
rec_prob = c()
for (id in active_ids){
  # extract historic data on the inmate (no future data)
  inmate_history = Rossi.2[Rossi.2$id == id & Rossi.2$stop <= time_today,]
  rec_prob = c(rec_prob, recidivism_prob(id, inmate_history, look_ahead_time))
}

# save to data frame
recidivism_risk = data.frame(id=ids, prob=rec_prob)
```

Now I wish to determine how well my predictions did so I want to divide the active prisoners into deciles and determine how many were actually arrested during the time horizon we are looking at.

```
# divide into deciles
recidivism_risk = recidivism_risk  %>% mutate(quantile = ntile(prob, 10))

# loop through deciles and count the number of actual prisoners who experienced recidivism
arrested_in_decile = c()
for (decile in 10:1){
  arrested_in_decile = c(
    arrested_in_decile,
    sum(arrested_ids %in% recidivism_risk$id[recidivism_risk$quantile == decile])
  )
}

# see the output
data.frame(decile=1:10, n_arrested=arrested_in_decile)
```

Which produces

```
decile n_arrested
1       1         12
2       2          8
3       3         10
4       4          4
5       5          5
6       6          5
7       7          5
8       8          7
9       9          3
10     10          1
```

At least the model does a better job than nothing. But of course this is not made out-of-sample either. I am mostly adding this answer in hopes of feedback.

**EDIT**

The first code snippet can be replaced by the following faster and less calc-by-hand solution

```
# imagine we have a model and are observing inmates who've been released 26 weeks ago
time_today = 26  
look_ahead_time = 26

# use dplyr for ease of use and performance improvement
library(dplyr)
active_inmates = Rossi.2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%  # one row per inmate
  filter(stop <= time_today) %>%  # only keep historic data
  filter(all(arrest.time == 0)) %>%  # remove all that already experienced recidivism
  filter(stop == max(stop))  # keep only last observed covariates for each inmate

arrested_inmates = Rossi.2 %>% 
  filter(stop > time_today) %>%  # only look at inmates after the landmarking date
  filter(arrest.time == 1)  # only keep inmates that were arrested


# fit for all active inmates
fitted = survfit(mod.allison.2, newdata = active_inmates)

# save to data frame
recidivism_risk = data.frame(id=active_inmates$id, prob=1-fitted$surv[look_ahead_time,])
```

Comment: I would not advocate this approach because it is not a reflection of what is actually happening to these people. You still must condition on their actual employment status, and you have introduced a more complex model which risks being inaccurate. Memorylessness is assumed but not tested with this method. What you say is employment change censors **parolee** (they are not inmates anymore) and their hazard is at time 0. Your model could be useful if you wanted to anticipate the effects of a rehabilitation/employment program... but that's not what you asked.

Comment: I am well aware that this approach does not reflect what is actually happening. But I am afraid I need these kind of workaround to get an indication of whom is most likely to experience recidivism. I am more than welcoming alternative approaches - any thoughtful solution is better than none I suppose.

Comment: I may not understand as well. It seems to me your question is: what fraction of parolees recidivate after 6 weeks? To answer that, the empirical KM estimate simply says: `summary(survfit(Surv(start, stop, arrest.time)~1), times=6*7)`

Comment: Well no that is not what I am asking. Let me clarify: given a list of parolees I want to rank them in order of who is most likely to recidivism within a certain time horizon. In this approach I disregard the path history of the parolees (certainly not optimal).

Comment: It turns out that *ranking* and *probability estimates* are very different. The Cox model linear predictors can rank people. But I don't know if they're 80% likely to *recidivate* or 20% likely to recidivate. Two approaches to obtaining risk estimates: truncate the log hazard ratios and use a scoring based approach to aggregate the cumulative hazard function and obtain risk scores (this was used in Framingham) or integrate the predicted hazard function (this was used for the Gail risk score). There are maybe too many questions in your question.

Comment: I see @AdamO - I just wanted the probability in order to rank by these to identify the high-risk people. I will look into Framingham and Gail and see whether it helps solving my problem. Thank you - and please send any reference if you've got some.

Comment: See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5084773/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `survfit` object stratifies on employment when your question says nothing about employment. Merely omit employment from the covariates in the call to `survfit` to obtain a univariate Kaplan-Meier curve and estimate the recidivism probability from that. KM curves provide unbiased probability estimates in right censored data. Evaluate survival at 6 weeks by either looking at the graph, or using predict. Inference and CI bounds can also be obtained from `predict.survfit` methods. See `?predict.survfit` for info on how to use these functions.

Comment: I wouldn’t exactly call it stratify. To me stratify means different baseline hazards, which isn’t modelled here. The plot simply shows a survival curve for the inmate if he was employed and if he was not. Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @mr.bjerre you may be unaware that there is a rigorous connection between fitting separate KM curves and stratifying the Cox proportional hazards model. The hazard function uniquely determines the survival curve. Showing survival in two groups with a KM curve is stratification by that group-assignment.

Comment: But still stratify means different *baseline* hazard curves, but they are the same in the two plotted survival curves. I'll propose an edit to your post showing that the curves share the __same baseline hazard__.

Comment: I'll admit that it might be a question of wording we are discussing.